# How to selectively indent Sphinx .rst (reStructuredText) files

Tags: indent

As per [indentation section](https://documentation-style-guide-sphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style-guide.html#indentation) of the Style guide for Sphinx-based documentations:

> Indent with 2 spaces.
>
> Except:
>
> `toctree` directive requires a 3 spaces indentation.

So how to set Vim to auto-indent the rst file while typing, so that it indents with 2 spaces while with 3 spaces for `toctree` directives?

Comment: I dont know what level of indent support exists for RST, but you could potentially wrap it up in a custom indentexpr function that calculates the appropriate indent based on that directive and defaults to the original otherwise.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for the direction, then that would be where I look into.